# AttachedCommandBehaviour MouseEventargs as commandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364780/new-wpf-window-only-shows-underneath-originating-window) and I have the same problem but I have command in view model. Can I pass `MouseEventargs` like `CommandParameter` and how?

```
acb:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseDoubleClick" acb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding Command}"
acb:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="{???}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Blend for this and do something like this with interaction triggers. In your command parameter when the Execute delegate is fired the Mouse EventArgs will be present..

```
 <Button>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick" >
         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}"
             PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

If you can't use interactivity dlls Try this..

```
public static class MouseDoubleClickBehavior
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hooks up a weak event against the source Selectors MouseDoubleClick
    /// if the Selector has asked for the HandleDoubleClick to be handled
    ///�
    /// If the source Selector has expressed an interest in not having its
    /// MouseDoubleClick handled the internal reference
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnHandleDoubleClickCommandChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement ele = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (ele != null)
        {
            ele.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseDoubleClick;
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                ele.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseDoubleClick;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TheCommandToRun : The actual ICommand to run
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DoubleClickCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(MouseDoubleClickBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ICommand)null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHandleDoubleClickCommandChanged)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the TheCommandToRun property. �
    /// </summary>
    public static ICommand GetDoubleClickCommand(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (ICommand)d.GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the TheCommandToRun property. �
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetDoubleClickCommand(DependencyObject d, ICommand value)
    {
        d.SetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty, value);
    }

    #region Handle the event

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoke the command we tagged.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //check for double clicks.
        if (e.ClickCount != 2)
            return;
        FrameworkElement ele = sender as FrameworkElement;

        DependencyObject originalSender = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
        if (ele == null || originalSender == null)
            return;

        ICommand command = (ICommand)(sender as DependencyObject).GetValue(DoubleClickCommandProperty);

        if (command != null)
        {
            if (command.CanExecute(null))
                command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and bind using this - MouseDoubleClickBehavior.DoubleClickCommand="{Binding SomeCommand}"

Comment: I know this way but I don't have System.Windows.Interactivity.dll and I'm not allowed to add new .dlls in my project so I can't use it. I try to do it with AttachedCommandBehaviour. But I think it's impossible.